Having problems building Libcurl x64 library for Visual Studio 2022
I have cloned the latest version of LibCurl onto my machine and am trying to build a static debug instance with nMake to use in my Visual Studio 2022 project. I have been referring to this winbuild documentation and got an x86 debug library built with no problems.
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17 debug=yes

However, I realized I needed the x64 version instead.
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=17 machine=x64 debug=yes

It doesn't work though, keeps giving me fatal errors:
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" /NOLOGO /F MakefileBuild.vc' : return code '0x2'

I am not sure how to proceed.
EDIT: I finally figured out what was wrong after reviewing this post. Turns out I wasn't following directions and was trying to build the library with Developer Powershell instead of x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022. Developer Powershell kept trying to use x86 nMake to build. Just for good measure I deleted all my previous builds and re-cloned the repository, then ran my build commands again in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt and everything went smoothly.

It should have other errors prior that last one. Please post all errors or a few top errors.

@3CxEZiVlQ
When it gets about halfway through "Generating Code..."
`NMAKE: fatal error U1077: 'link.exe /incremental:no /libpath:''..[followed by what appears to be hundreds of various directories]' : return code '0x458' Stop.`


This is still not the first error in the build output.

@3CxEZiVlQ
..\builds\libcurl-vc17-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel-obj-curl\tool_hugehelp.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

You should remove the previous build and run the full rebuild.

@3CxEZiVlQ thank you for your help, after some research I finally got it to work. I deleted all the builds and cloned the repository once more, then with the guidance of this Stackoverflow comment I ran the build in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 instead of Developer Powershell. Turns out Developer Powershell kept trying to use the x86 version of nMake.
